# Copy data table each row and editing each row

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I need to copy each row in a data table with its child row, editing each row in C#.

[image: Visual example]

Please check my code.

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[13] { new DataColumn("FIX1"), new DataColumn("FIX2"), new DataColumn("SEQNO") 
,new DataColumn("FIX3"),new DataColumn("TRANSACTIONCODE"),new DataColumn("FIX4"),
new DataColumn("CreditAccNo"),new DataColumn("CreditBRNO"),new DataColumn("CreditDate"),
new DataColumn("1LinkCode"),new DataColumn("Debit/creditResonding"),new DataColumn("InstruementNo1"),
new DataColumn("InstruementNo2")});

da.Fill(ds);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        row["FIX1"] = "0";
        row["FIX2"] = "0";
        row["SEQNO"] = "1";
        row["FIX3"] = "0";
        row["TRANSACTIONCODE"] = "ZNBPDR";
        row["FIX4"] = "0";
        row["CreditAccNo"] = "2010100002";
        row["CreditBRNO"] = "2";
        row["CreditDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        row["1LinkCode"] = "71";
        row["Debit/creditResonding"] = "2";
        row["InstruementNo1"] = "130row2";
        row["InstruementNo2"] = "130row2";
        txt += row[column.ColumnName].ToString() + "|";
    }

    //Add new line.
    txt += "\r \n";
    txt = "";
}
```

Comment: Please post exactly where your problem is, what is not working with the current code, what is the expected result. Maybe extending your code to match the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. For now I see some variables not defined and your question seems unclear. Imagine you have to answer this question without knowing the context in the first place.

Comment: At least remove the `foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)` loop

Comment: It is bad practice to add rows to an object while enumerating through the object (for loop).  Instead you can copy all the rows using DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x).CopyToDataTable();